# Can't link Xdebug to PHP 5.4

Tags: php5, pecl, pear, xdebug

Today I installed/updated my previous `php 5.3.x` to **5.4.11**. Did it accordingly [how do I upgrade from php 5.3 to php 5.4.6 in ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/questions/420286/how-do-i-upgrade-from-php-5-3-to-php-5-4-6-in-ubuntu)

Install was successful, but it seemed to me, that `xdebug` was outdated due to a warning message when viewing `php -v` to check the success of installation.

So I updated `pear/pecl`, removed previous installation of xdebug
`sudo pecl uninstall xdebug`

Set `php_ini` setting in `pear/pecl` and tried once more to `sudo pecl install xdebug`. When installation was finishing for some reason it showed me, that `php_ini` is not pointing to `php.ini`(when it actually was).

Nevertheless, installation was successful except, that when I tried to add `/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so` to a file in `/etc/php5/mods-available` and symlink to that file in `/etc/php5/conf.d`, after restarting server I got for `php -v`

```
sandbox@ubuntu:~$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: php_body_write in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.11-1~precise+1 (cli) (built: Jan 24 2013 15:22:16)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? I really need **Xdebug** to be on my side)

**UPDATE:**
Forgot to mention, that everything is happening on Ubuntu Server 12.04, that is located on VirtualBox under Windows host system.

**UPDATE 1:**
I was suggested to move `20090626+lfs` directory elsewhere, since it might shadow the newer version, but no. After moving it away I tried to reinstall xdebug( `sudo pecl uninstall xdebug & sudo pecl install xdebug` ), but for somereason it was installed to same place. When viewing `pecl` config I see

```
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs
```

, but during installation of xdebug it prints out following

```
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php5-dev` needed to be installed.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case `php5-dev` was already installed and i got the `unable to load...` message, too. Uninstalling xdebug did the trick for me:

```
sudo pecl uninstall xdebug
```

and then

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

the install directory changed now and i needed to modify my `/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini` to point to the new xdebug.so

Answer (score 0):

Include the follow lines in the php.ini file.

> [xdebug]
>   zend_extension=xdebug.so

Edit the file **/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini**

> xdebug.remote_enable=1
>   xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
>   xdebug.remote_mode=req
>   xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
>   xdebug.remote_port=9000

In the follow URL http://icdif.com/computing/2011/05/01/xdebug-ubuntu/ you get the simple tutorial to setup the xdebug but do not forget to run the command:

> sudo pecl install xdebug (this commando

restart the apache

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

and perfert!

Works like a charme!